# FFmpeg Command Executing

Tags: android, ffmpeg

How to Disable audio perticular time interval in **FFMPEG** i.e if video is 10 min then starting  2min to 5min between audio disable is possible ? and how  set in ffmpeg command .
I know disable audio using **-an** command but i want to disable between time interval disable audio.
Plz help thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

See the [`volume` audio filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#volume) from FFmpeg. It supports the [timeline editing](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Timeline-editing) feature.

```
ffmpeg -i input -af volume='between(t,2*60,5*60)':volume=0 -codec:v copy output
```